# Screen brightness in Ubuntu not working

Tags: brightness, ati

Hardware: HP DVD6t, AMD Radeon 6700
OS: Natty 32-bit.

I have researched a lot on this and basically most of the solutions that are on the internet / stackexchange revolves around the brightness buttons not working.

If you are brightness buttons are not working then you can do a million things to get it work

i) install applets

ii) modify /etc/brightness file

iii) write scripts to modify brightness.

However, my problem is not brightness buttons, but the brightness delivered by the video driver itself. My brightness is set to 0, but still actual_brightness shows 5

I'd like to add that I use a 32-bit OS and the drivers usually come on 64-bits.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your /etc/default/grub file as following:

- Type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Find this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- Change it to one of the following (on my system only the first one worked):

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux
   acpi_backlight=vendor"` `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash
   acpi_backlight=vendor"` `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash
   acpi_osi=Linux"`

- Open a terminal (ctrl + alt + T) and type: `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot.